# How to find closest datetimes to 6-hour intervals?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, time, group-by

I have table of several million records containing indicating how many "things" (`int`) existed at random times (`datetime`) throughout the day.  (One day could have 100's or 1000's of records.)

I need to report how many "things" existed at *roughly* `[00:00, 06:00, 12:00, 18:00]` daily ... meaning there **may or may not** be records for those times, so if there isn't I'd need the **closest** record (before or after).

I tried a few methods but the runtimes aren't feasible for production. There's got to be a more efficient method that I'm not thinking of. Here's one of my attempts but I also tried using a `UNION` query, as well as running 4 separate queries from PHP. (The solution could be in any of MySQL, PHP, or JS/JQuery).

```sql
SELECT dt, SUM(things) thgs
FROM myTable
WHERE dt IN (SELECT MIN(dt) FROM myTable GROUP BY DATE(dt))
   OR dt IN (SELECT DATE_SUB(MIN(DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)), INTERVAL 6 HOUR) FROM myTable
             GROUP BY DATE_SUB(DATE(DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)), INTERVAL 6 HOUR))
   OR dt IN (SELECT DATE_SUB(MIN(DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 12 HOUR)), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) FROM myTable
             GROUP BY DATE_SUB(DATE(DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 12 HOUR)), INTERVAL 12 HOUR))
   OR dt IN (SELECT DATE_SUB(MIN(DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 18 HOUR)), INTERVAL 18 HOUR) FROM myTable
             GROUP BY DATE_SUB(DATE(DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 18 HOUR)), INTERVAL 18 HOUR))
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this question, but this is generally how I solve a similar sort of thing when presenting operational statistics to managers curious about how many students are using our "learning portals" at any given time:

```
SELECT tmp.`id`, tmp.`start_at`, tmp.`until_at`, COUNT(DISTINCT ss.`id`) as `things`
  FROM `Status` ss INNER JOIN (SELECT (h*1000+t*100+u*10+v+1) as `id`,
                                      DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), INTERVAL ((h*1000+t*100+u*10+v+1) - 1) * 6 HOUR) as `start_at`,
                                      DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d 06:00:00'), INTERVAL ((h*1000+t*100+u*10+v+1) - 1) * 6 HOUR), INTERVAL 1 SECOND) as `until_at`
                                 FROM (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a,
                                      (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b,
                                      (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c,
                                      (SELECT 0 v UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d
                                WHERE (h*1000+t*100+u*10+v+1) > 0) tmp ON ss.`event_at` BETWEEN tmp.`start_at` AND tmp.`until_at`
 WHERE ss.`event_at` >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
 GROUP BY tmp.`id`, tmp.`start_at`, tmp.`until_at`
 ORDER BY tmp.`id`;
```

**How this works:**

- the most nested subquery generates a sequence of numbers from 1 ~ 10,000
- this sequence is used to work out time periods of — for this example — six hours
- there are roughly 10,000 six-hour periods in 7 years
- group the "things" by `start_at` and `until_at`
- filter on a reasonable timeframe

I tested this on my development workstation, which has a 4th Gen Core i7 and 32GB RAM. The query took just under 30 seconds to return data on a statistics table with 27-million+ records.

Here is a sample ... not that it will mean anything beyond showing the above SQL is cromulent:

[image: SQL Output]

> **Note:** The development box does not contain any data for the current month, hence the gap.

In the event that you do not want to show periods where there are zero "things", then that can be filtered out afterwards.

If you (or anyone else) is still looking for a solution to this sort of problem, this might offer something to think about.